# AWS Lambda Layer for python requests library

Tags: aws-lambda, python-requests

A college is using python request library bundled into his lambda function.
However, I want to have the library available as a lambda layer.

Plenty of instructions on how to compile a download of the bins if you are in a linux machine, but I am on windows.

I know for psycopg2 there are pre-compiled copies you can download - am kind of hoping that someone knows of a requests pre-compiled source ?

(btw - I can do some coding in python, but compiling and packaging are voodoo magic to me)

Any simple solution to this welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - why do you want to create a whole lambda layer just for the request library? Just install it before zipping your Lambda and push it. Don't make life hard for yourself.

Comment: But as a layer it would be easier for other functions (& developers) to reuse, no?

Comment: Not if it's just one package. With that being the massively common `requests` library. Install it & package it. You don't 'reuse' publicly available libraries unless you have huge libraries i.e. for data engineering

Comment: https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers

Comment: Your colleague's decision to bundle it the right decision. In most cases, if your dependencies are part of your runtime's ecosystem, you just bundle it together with the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows better to use docker with Amazon Linux operating system for layer creation. Because lambda running over on Amazon Linux.